# Update model objects across different activities

Tags: android, architecture

Lets say I have 2 activities:

- A: A ListView displaying articles titles. Data is fetched from a web server and converted from XML to a list of ArticleSummary. Only user titles and id are returned by the server. Click on a title starts activity B.
- B: A form to edit an article. Article is fetched from server. When the user hits OK, modifications are sent to the server and activity closed.

When the user go back to activity A, I would like to update the article title without any additional web request.

I was thinking about the following solution:

1. When article is modified, send a broadcast event with article id and new attributes values.
2. Listen for this event on activity A
3. Update the ArticleSummary object
4. notify data changed on ListView

Is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a shared data model between different Activities, you can place it in an extension of the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.  Or, you can use a singleton.  Just reload the data from the shared location when the `ListView` activity is restarted.

As Fredley alluded to, if you have are communicating with a server you should be sure to do so in a separate background thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use startActivityForResult() to launch activity and managed returned data.

Check the "Returning a Result from a Screen" section in the part below. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html